# CommitFailureHandler: How does it work?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

while I know what CommitFailureHandler, that was introduced with 6.1, does, I don't see how it does it, when I look into the code.

Can anyone tell me, how (with which method) CommitFailureHandler tells EF, that a transaction has been commited before there was an issue?

Wishes,
Manfred

Answer (score 1):

The CommitFailureHandler does not tell EF the transaction has been committed.
When EF commits transactions, it invokes the db transaction interceptor via DbTransactionDispatcher.Commit().

As CommitFailureHandler extends IDbTransactionInterceptor, its Committing() and Committed() methods are called. One can extend the CommitFailureHandler with your own class, as these methods are implemented in TransactionHandler, which is a parent of CommitFailureHandler.

Thanks, Boris

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your reply. While I knew this document, I didn't see, how the code is implementing this concept.

But after giving it a 2nd look now, it seems like my first look wasn't that good, cause I can see (clearly now) that Commited tests for interceptionContext.Exception != null and when there has been an exception and when there is a row in the transaction-table, this exception is cleared using interceptionContext.Exception = null;

Thanks and best wishes from Austria
Manfred